Manhwa with a female MC who reincarnated as a black haired villainess
My brother told me about a manhwa with a dark haired character. What he told me was that the heroine of that story is reincarnated as a villainess in the novel (I think) she was reading. The villainess in the novel tortured the male lead, as in mentally and physically abused him, til he lost his mind and killed the villainess at the end. When she was reincarnated as the villainess, she decided to change her fate by treating the male lead differently. The male lead was a slave.
edit: my brother told me the ml might have had a red or black hair color
ps: uh, my brother said he had found the manhwa already and it seems like theres a little bit of mistake with the description that he gave me but the manhwa is called "The Villainess Just Wants to Live in Peace!"

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you know when he read this or on what site?

Villainess manhwas are dime a dozen, so we would really need more details than "isekai, villainess, black hair"

Is there an isekai otome type that doesn't have black hair?

Plenty of novel with this trend. However the reader is your brother so I may think it is "The Way to Protect the Female Lead’s Older Brother". Although the story is completely different. That is only popular manhwa about ml slave which owner is fmc.
